# Crossposting from Arts&Craft

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/11305/15744) on the Arts&Crafts stackexchange, a few weeks ago, about how to deal with coating old wood.

I initially didn't think about posting it on woodworking.SE (actually, I didn't even realize there was such a stack - good to know), but a moderator from A&C suggested that it may be better suited here. Besides, the current answer I have on A&C does not really give a solution, although it does an excellent job at explaining why I have my problem. In fact, I may not have chosen the most appropriate site, although my question wasn't off-topic on A&C.

I know [crossposting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/325443) on stackexchange. But since a moderator suggested it over there, would it be acceptable to crosspost here? Do you think I could get valuable answers?

Note: I also [tried chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22025/2022/10/21) to check this, but to no avail.

Comment: Sorry we missed your question in chat, and thanks for posting in meta. Your question seems like a good fit here. The mods over there can also migrate your existing question over there to woodworking, to help you avoid crossposting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly looks like a reasonable question for WW.  I'm pretty sure someone will have some advice that might work well for you.  I even have some ideas. I don't have a problem with it, just make sure your question really focuses on finishing it and the results you want.  If you have any before AND after pictures that show what you don't want it can help.

Comment: Thank you. the question has been migrated. I'd really like to hear about these ideas, if you have a bit of time to put into this.